# Returned value is partial and not full

Tags: c++

I have a `file.txt` where I'm reading each line and I wan't to handle those lines. The file contains IP, Nicknames and some values. I want to save only the IP addresses to another file, but before that I'm checking the result returned by my function (`char* get_ip(char arr[])`).
The problem is the returned value, it's showing me only a partial, e.g:

normal IP address: `66.55.44.33`
My return: `66.55.44`

Edit:

There are 2 functions: `main()` and `get_ip()`

```
//<----------- FUNCTION get_ip() -------------------- ><br />

    char* get_ip(char buff[]){

    char line[32];

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buff); i++){
        if(buff[i] == '.'){
            if(isdigit(buff[i + 1])){
                i = 0;
                while(buff[i] != ' '){
                    line[i] = buff[i];
                    i++;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(isdigit(line[0]))
        return line;
    else
        return 0;
}

//<------------ FUNCTION int main() --------------------->


    int main(){
    // variable, opening folder etc.

    char buff[64], *line;

    while(!feof(fph)){
        fgets(buff, 63, fph);
        line = get_ip(buff);

        if(line)
            cout << line << "\n";
    }

    } // main() func. end
```

Comment: Are you sure your tags are correct?

Comment: `cout`? Looks like C++ code to me, not C#.

Comment: @Tudor: This is clearly not C#...

Comment: @Tudor: subject makes me think it is C (as well as all but one line)

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I guess `cout` means he's using C++.

Comment: Share a sample txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should show more code: the signature of you function at least.

You are allocating `buff` on stack, and then return it.

But arrays are `never` returned by value, they are decayed to pointer-to-first-element.
That means, that when you use your function like this:

```
char[32] myFunction(...);

char ip[32] = myFunction(...);
```

your `ip` array is initialized with a pointer to array (`line`) that was destroyed after going out of scope when `myFunction` returns!

That means, it contains a garbage and you are lucky that you get even partial result from it (although if it was complete garbage you would probably track the problem easier).

The possible remedies is to use `std::string` (which I recommend) or to pass the pointer to preallocated array to `myFunction` (C-style solution):

```
char[32] ip;

myFunction(ip, ...);
```

Comment: So my guess was correct -- the problem is that you return the address of local variable.

Answer (score 3):

Current expected behavior is not defined, as `line` is a local variable, you are not allowed to return from the function. If you want it to be separate buffer from `buff` you should use malloc instead of the declaration `char line[32];`

Answer (score 2):

One issue might be in the line:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buff); i++){
```

Specifically the statement

```
sizeof(buff)
```

While you might have expected this to return 64, the size of the buffer, you are forgetting how C arrays almost always decay to pointers, so this is actually returning 4( if 32-bit) or 8(if 64-bit), the size of a `char *`.

You need to explicitly pass in a size.